# Why does my window reopen when closed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I was testing my friend's `Tkinter` code, and came across this bizarre behaviour.

When I use the Windows 'X' button (top-right of window) to close this Tk window (class/method?), it closes, then reopens a second afterwards. A second click of the 'X' button finally closes the window.
Here's the code for the window (assume that all button commands are defined):

```
from tkinter import *
import os, string, random

def generate():
    length = 13
    chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
    random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
    master = Tk()
    master.title("Secure Password Generator")
    master.geometry("310x24")
    master.maxsize(310,24)
    master.minsize(310,24)
    text = Text(master)
    ranPass = ''
    for i in range(length):
        ranPass += random.choice(chars)
    text.insert(INSERT,"Your secure password is %s." % ranPass)
    text.config(state=DISABLED)
    text.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title ("Sleak Test")
root.geometry("100x500")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button5 = Button(app)
button5.grid()
button5.configure(text = "Password Generator", fg='green', bg='black', command=generate)
root.mainloop()
try:
    root.destroy()
except tkinter.TclError:
    pass
```

Is there a reason that I would have to click the close button on the window *twice*?

EDIT: Made the example actually work. Sorry guys!

SECOND EDIT: Ok, this is strange. This works perfectly, which means there must be something wrong with the code elsewhere. This just got strange.

Comment: On my machine, the window does not appear a second time.

Comment: *"assume that all button commands are defined"* is not helpful - please edit to provide a working [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including any imports (on which note it looks like you're doing `from tkinter import *` - don't).

Comment: All `[X]`-icon-button associated services come from Tkinter ability to configure an event-handler routine for this externally operated icon-botton. Setting something like this `root.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW', lambda:None )` can change that behaviour. There may be more complex arrangements to emulate your experience. While the rest of your experience / story is not reproducible from your excerpted code-snippet.

Comment: Are you trying to run this from within IDLE (any platform) or some other graphical IDE (Windows only)? If so, you often need a `root.destroy()` after the `root.mainloop()`. The docs explain why somewhere; if this is the problem I can dig up the details. If you're not sure: If you're running this script by typing `pythonw` from the command line or by double-clicking in Explorer, this isn't your problem; otherwise, please explain exactly how you're running it and I can try to explain how to tell.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, IDLE. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not be your problem, but, quoting from the [`Tkinter Book`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm):

> **Note:** Some Python development environments have problems running Tkinter examples like this one. The problem is usually that the enviroment uses Tkinter itself, and the **mainloop** call and the **quit** calls interact with the environment’s expectations. Other environments may misbehave if you leave out the explicit **destroy** call. If the example doesn’t behave as expected, check for Tkinter-specific documentation for your development environment.
>
> …
>
> The **destroy** call is only required if you run this example under certain development environments; it explicitly destroys the main window when the event loop is terminated. Some development environments won’t terminate the Python process unless this is done.

What this means is that if you launch your app from within IDLE or another tkinter-based IDE—or, on Windows, in certain cases, from *any* graphical IDE—you may have to add `root.destroy()` after your `root.mainloop()`.

If you suspect this may be the problem, and you're using an IDE, the first thing to test is running the problem outside the IDE. Open up a cmd.exe ("DOS prompt") window, and do this:

```
cd C:\Path\To\Your\Program
C:\Path\To\Python\pythonw.exe YourScript.py
```

If it now works properly, this is most likely the problem. So the next step is to add the `root.destroy()` and make sure it works properly both from the command line and from IDLE.

However, note that in some cases this will lead to tkinter raising and catching an exception and logging a spurious error message about it. If you're building an application for distribution, you might want to do something like:

```
root.mainloop()
try:
    root.destroy()
except tkinter.TclError:
    # When the destroy isn't necessary, it's actually illegal. And we
    # don't know from inside the app whether it's necessary or not.
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it. Thanks to @abarnert for helping.

If anyone else is wondering this, my friend forgot to put a `root.destroy()` call after the `root.mainloop()` call. Although including this `destroy()` method throws a `_tkinter.TclError` in IDLE, it does work perfectly on compilation.

Many thanks.

RE-EDIT: Ok, I get it now. It turns out that my friend was importing both the `tkinter` and the `Tkinter` modules, of which I have both due to my `Python 2.7` installation. This meant that the program was attempting to call each `Tkinter`-related function *twice*.
Well done me.

Comment: As explained in my answer, you may want to handle that exception; there are other cases besides IDLE where the exception may happen, and you probably don't want end users seeing it. (And, as far as I know, there's no way to tell from inside the app whether your parent has set up an event loop that yours will interfere with, which means there's no way to tell but to just `try` the `destroy`.)

Comment: You should not have to call `root.destroy()` after `mainloop()`, since `mainloop()` never exits until _after_ the root window has been destroyed. Also, importing two tkinter libraries -- while bad -- won't give the behavior you say it does. Importing along doesn't create nor destroy any windows.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Anything to back this up? Because abarnert's solution (which is now my accepted answer) quotes from the [`Tkinter Book`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-again.htm), which suggests that Windows IDEs operating on `Tk` have issues working with `Tkinter`.

Comment: @Helloman892: I don't quite understand your question. The actual implementation of mainloop is such that is designed to exit after the root window has been destroyed. Now sure, if you're running tkinter inside some other environment, that environment might change the default behavior, but at its core, mainloop exits when the root window is destroyed. That's what it's designed to do.

Comment: @Bryan: The question was 'is there anything you can provide  (e.g. a link) that proves your statement?', and as for the implementation of `mainloop()`, I know. I am fully aware that `mainloop()` **should** exit, but it doesn't due to it being used inside IDLE, a `Tkinter` IDE.

Anyway, I think we're done here. My question has been answered, and so I am pleased to provide the fixed code to my friend.